# EasyAdmin: "Unable to transform value for property path XY: Expected a string."

Tags: php, symfony, symfony2-easyadmin

When clicking the "Edit" link in EasyAdmin's list view of an entity that contains a field with `type="date"`, I'm getting this error message:

> Unable to transform value for property path "birthday": Expected a string.

I have this in my entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="date")
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 * @Assert\Date()
 */
private $birthday;
```

Answer (score 3):

There are 2 solutions.

**Quick and dirty (Symfony < 5)**

Change this in `config/packages/easy_admin.yaml`:

```
easy_admin:
    entities:
        MyEntity:
            form:
                fields:
                    - { property: 'birthday', type: 'date' }
```

See https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/EasyAdminBundle/book/edit-new-configuration.html#the-special-form-view for further configuration details.

**Quick and clean**

`@Assert\Date()` will be deprecated for `type="date"` fields in Symfony 4.2 (and thus probably removed in Symfony 5). The validation relies on the `\DateTimeInterface` type hint of the setter. In total:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="date")
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 */
private $birthday;

public function setBirthday(?\DateTimeInterface $birthday): self
{
    // ...
    return $this;
}
```

See https://github.com/EasyCorp/EasyAdminBundle/issues/2381 for some background information.